# git single user - several computers / repositories

Tags: git

I am introducing git but currently working by myself in git environment. 
I use stationary, virtual servers, local virtual servers, and laptop. I need to be able to identify from where I have done changes. How can that be solved?

At later stage I might of course introduce more resources that would work in the git environment.

To clarify: Since I am working as a single developer it is more important for me to track from which machine the commits/pull/fetch was done, rather then user/user.email.

Should I add different user credentials, like this?

**[user.email]**

- git config --global user.email "physical-server-1@company.com"
- git config --global user.email "virtual-server-1@company.com"
- git config --global user.email "local-virtual-server-2@company.com"
- git config --global user.email "laptop@company.com"

**[user.name]**

- git config --global user.name "physical-server-1"
- git config --global user.name "virtual-server-1"
- git config --global user.name "local-virtual-server-2"
- git config --global user.name "laptop"

Comment: I'm not sure it should *matter* on which machine you make changes. Are the changes specific to a particular machine? In that case, you should be using branches to track machine-specific code bases.

Comment: Why do you need this? It seems like you're adding unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two solutions:

1. Use separate emails/names as you mention above
2. Sign your commits with different private keys (one for each machine). See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Signing-Your-Work